# How to create a new div dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a div dynamically with Javascript and trying to register the data in a database with PHP. But I'm testing to print the info that I filled before I start to register in the database but its just printing the info from the "main" div but not from the div's that creates dynamically. How should I create the div's?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x <= max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++;
      $(wrapper).append('<div id="loopdiv"><h2>Dilemma</h2> Video länk: <br><textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolink"></textarea><div>1.<input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>2.<input type="text" name="answer2" id="answer"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>3.<input type="text" name="answer3" id="answer"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><div>4.<input type="text" name="answer4" id="answer"/><select><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select></div><br><br></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});
```

```html
<form action="adddilemman.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <br><br>  
  <div name="loopdiv" id="loopdiv">
    <h2 name="h2" id="h2">Dilemma</h2> 
    Video länk: <br>
    <textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolink"></textarea>
    <div>
        1.
        <input type="text" name="answer1" id="answer"/>
         <select>
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
           <option value="5">5</option>
           <option value="6">6</option>
           <option value="7">7</option>
           <option value="8">8</option>
           <option value="9">9</option>
           <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        2.
        <input type="text" name="answer2" id="answer"/>
        <select>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>              
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
       </select>           
    </div>
    <div>
        3.
        <input type="text" name="answer3" id="answer"/>
        <select>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        4.
        <input type="text" name="answer4" id="answer"/>
        <select>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <br><br></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <button class="add_field_button">Lägg till fler svar</button> 
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

This is the codes that prints the things that I write in the fields

```
<?php
If(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])!=''){

   If($_REQUEST['videolink']=='' || $_REQUEST['answer1']=='' || $_REQUEST['answer2']==''|| $_REQUEST['answer3']=='' || $_REQUEST['answer4']==''){

      Echo "please fill the empty field.";

   } Else {

      Echo $_REQUEST['videolink'];
   }
}
?>
```

Is there any way to print the fields that I create dynamically?

Comment: You are adding, in a loop, a div with the same id - that's not going to be valid. In fact, looking along the html string that gets appended there are several elements that have ids specified. Rather than using a standard `submit` button, change it's type to `button` and use javascript to process the form and submit the data

Comment: Beside the fact already pointed by RamRaider (unique Id's) I don't understand what you mean with 'print the fields'. Can you please explain?

Comment: The [code works](https://jsfiddle.net/ah01y4et/) to create the new elements, even though the IDs may be borked.  If you want to populate these new fields from PHP you will need to use AJAX request(s).

Comment: What do the select menus do?

Comment: @Franco i'm mean that im trying to see what i wrote in the fields before i regester it in the database (to see if its working)

Comment: @RamRaider i'm trying to process the form in Javascript instead, i'm not so good at javascript.. any tips? 
The select is for putting some pionts for every field

Comment: @James I'm not good at AJAX, can u recommend something helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly I can offer no guidance really with jQuery but using standard vanilla Javascript in conjunction with PHP you could do something like this. Your original form was using multi-part/formdata as the enctype so that can be emulated easily using the FormData object available in core javascript.

To send the data to the desired `adddilemman.php` script, change the url in the ajax call. So, instead of using `document.location.href` change it to `'adddilemman.php'`

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        ob_clean();
        /* This is here only to simplify development and display here */

        $delimiter=isset( $_POST['delimiter'] ) ? $_POST['delimiter'] : '|';

        /* process form submission: for testing purposes just echo out data sent */
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value ) {
            if( $field!='delimiter' ){
                if( is_array( $value ) ) echo 'Array values: '.$field.'='.rtrim( str_replace( $delimiter, ',', implode( ' ', $value ) ), ',' ).'<br />';
                else echo 'String value: '.$field.'='.trim( str_replace( $delimiter, '', $value ) ).'<br />';
            }
        }


        exit(); 
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video do-hickey</title>
        <style>
            form,
            #loopdiv section{
                display:block!important;
                width:80%;
                height:auto;
                float:none;
                margin:0.25rem auto;    
                box-sizing:content-box;
            }
            h2{
                margin:0 auto 1rem auto;    
            }
            #loopdiv section{
                border:1px solid gray;
                clear:both;
                min-height:250px;
                padding:0.25rem;                
            }
            textarea,
            input[type='text'],
            select{
                width:40%;
                height:2rem;
            }
            label,
            section div{
                display:block;
                clear:both;
                float:left;
                min-width:80%;  
                width:auto;
            }
            div textarea,
            div input[type='text'],
            div select{
                /*float:right;  */
            }
            textarea{
                resize:none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript' charset='utf-8'>
            var max_input_fields=10;
            var delimiter='|';

            function http( data, callback ){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ) callback.call( this, xhr.response );
                };
                xhr.open( 'POST', document.location.href, true );
                xhr.send( data );
            }

            function cbhttp(r){
                document.querySelectorAll('output')[0].innerHTML=r  
            }

            function bindEvents(){
                var oBttnAdd=document.getElementById('bttnadd');
                var oBttnSub=document.getElementById('bttnsub');
                var oForm=document.getElementById('dynelems');
                var oParent=document.getElementById('loopdiv');

                oBttnSub.onclick=function(e){
                    /* scan the form and get values from all elements ( including dynamcially added ) and submit the form via xhr */
                    var col=oForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="text"],textarea,select');
                    var data=new FormData();
                        data.append('delimiter',delimiter);

                    for( var n in col ) if( col[n] && col[n].nodeType==1 ) {
                        data.append( col[n].name, col[n].value.replace( delimiter, '' ) + delimiter );
                    }
                    http.call( this, data, cbhttp );
                };

                oBttnAdd.onclick=function(e){
                    /* Add new rows based upon selected option from dropdown menu */
                    var col=oParent.querySelectorAll('section[data-id]');
                    var length=col.length;
                    if( length < max_input_fields ){
                        var newid=parseInt( col[ length-1 ].dataset.id ) + 1;
                        var clone=oParent.childNodes[1].cloneNode( true );
                            clone.dataset.id=newid;
                            /* Set new name for the textarea */
                            clone.childNodes[3].childNodes[1].name='videolink'+newid;

                        oParent.appendChild( clone );
                    }
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', bindEvents,false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='dynelems' action='adddilemman.php' method='post'>
            <div id='loopdiv'>
            <?php
                /* Data-id is used by js to determine next suitable id */
                echo "
                    <section data-id=1>
                        <h2>Dilemma</h2>
                        <div>Video länk:<textarea rows='1' cols='40' name='videolink1'></textarea></div>";

                for( $i=1; $i <= 4; $i++ ){

                    /* Add four text fields and four select menus */
                    echo "
                        <div>
                            Answer: <input type='text' name='answer{$i}[]'/>
                            <select name='options{$i}[]'>";

                    /* Add options to each select menu */
                    for( $j=1; $j <= 10; $j++ ){
                        echo "<option value={$j}>{$j}";
                    }

                    /* Close each nested div & select menu */
                    echo "
                            </select>
                        </div>";
                }
                /* Close initial section */
                echo "
                    </section>";

            ?>
            </div>

            <div class='input_fields_wrap'>
              <div></div> 
            </div>

            <input id='bttnadd' type='button' name='add_field_button' value='Lägg till fler svar'/>
            <input id='bttnsub' type='button' name='sub' value='Submit'/>
        </form>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have noticed now, when looking further at the html string you append in the loop that it should be the entire contents of the div with id `loopdiv` ~ so my code is not quite right in that respect. It should however be fairly straightforward to modify the code if needed...

Comment: If you are happy with the way the content is generated in your code then you might find simply using ajax ( as above ) with the FormData object gives you what you need without being confused by my code ;-)

Comment: I can't use AJAX. I tried your codes, it's working but not in the way that i want, i want that the whole div with the text area to repeats, not just the input fields, and i want to register the result in the database, so i was thinking to send the data to `adddilemman.php` so i can register it in the database with PHP

Comment: YOU ARE GREAT!! I fixed it, but how do i register the data in the database?

Comment: Final edit. If you were to copy my code into a new page and run it you will see in the results there are string values and array values. The tow tie together in that the textareas are sequentially number 1,2,3,... etc and the array values will have a corresponding number of entries so you should be able to tie the answers up in your php that processes the response. I'm off now to drink some gin - Happy Christmas, hope you resolve how to add to the db ~ should be fairly straightforward!

Comment: great, this works, but i'm still not understanding how i can save the data in the database (PS.. i'm gonna save the answers in a table and the textarea in another table) is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Your input element should be an array

Append below in your jQuery code

```
<div id="loopdiv">
  <h2>Dilemma</h2>
  Video länk: <br>
  <textarea type="text" rows="1" cols="40" name="videolink[]"></textarea>
  <div>1.
    <input type="text" name="answer1[]" id="answer"/>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>2.
    <input type="text" name="answer2[]" id="answer"/>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>3.
    <input type="text" name="answer3[]" id="answer"/>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>4.
    <input type="text" name="answer4[]" id="answer"/>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```